# Browser's default language setting would effect the language in cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, localization

I had a website and need localization, so add the "Language" field into the cookie, and use this field to record the localization: When open the website, it would found the language in cookie, or would use the browser's default language and save it into the cookie, and never changed until user change it manual

But recently I found a issue: I login the website, and got the language from browser, it's "en-us". Then I change the browser's default language to "es-mx", and reopen the browser and open my website. 
I found that the "Language" in cookie change to "es-mx", and my website display in Spanish.

My issue is: The browser's default language would effect the language of cookie? Or the "Language" should be another name in the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it would effect or not. You can check it by changing the name. I did the same thing using localStorage, it works well

Comment: it conflict with language from GTM.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it, if I change it to another word like "My_Language", it would not changed while changing the browser's default language.